# MVC posting via javascript to controller strange json object behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When a form is submitted I capture it in javascript. I do some validation and create a json object and pass that to $.post(). In my controller I have an object defined with the same definition as the json object. I'm finding if I don't access the json object in javascript then it's null when it gets to the controller. If I do an alert on it's fields then the controller has the values filled in. Any idea why this is happening?

```
$(function(){

        $("#VideoForm").submit(function () {
            var video = $("#txtVideo").val();

            var val = getVideoID(video);

            if (val.ID == -1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("Invalid url. Only Vimeo and YouTube are supported.")
                $("#txtVideo").val("")
                return false;
            }

            // if this is commented out then my controller parameter object is null
            // if this is uncommented then my controller parameter object is filled in
            //alert(val.ID);
            //alert(val.Source);

            $.post('/Home/Index', val, function (data) {
            });
        });

 function getVideoID(videolink){
            var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
            var match = videolink.match(regExp);

            if (match && match[7].length == 11)
            {
                //alert("youtube video id : "+ match[7]);
                alert("Youtube match");
                return { ID: match[7], Source: "youtube" };
            }

            regExp = "vimeo\\.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)";
            match = videolink.match(regExp);
            if(match)
            {
                var videoid = videolink.split('/')[videolink.split('/').length - 1];

                alert("Vimeo match");
                //alert("vimeo video id :"+videoid);
                return { ID: videoid, Source: "vimeo" };
            }
            else
            {
                return { ID: -1, Source: "" };
            }
        };
```

Comment: what does getVideoID do?

Comment: Returns an object. Updated original source.

Comment: That function returns data just fine though.

Comment: Perhaps some defensive coding could be enlightening.  Testing return values or attribute extractions before they are used in the next call, try/catch, that sort of thing.

Comment: I am testing the values. When I alert() out values they all work and everything works. As soon as I take the alert() out then no go. That's why I'm very confused.

Comment: @user441521 +1 for defensive coding. Also use a modern browser with js debugger - it might make tracking the bug easier.